# conflict between eqref and pdfcomment

Tags: annotations, pdfmark

I am trying to use pdfcomment to annotate a mathematical report and runs into issues when \eqref is present inside the text to be annotated. Below is a minimal non-working example. If I push the \eqref out of the pdfmarkupcomment, this error goes away.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}
\usepackage[author={Max Schlepzig}]{pdfcomment}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Following is energy equation 
\begin{align}
\label{eq:energy}
    E=mc^2
\end{align}
\pdfmarkupcomment[markup=Highlight,color=yellow]{Of course, you can highlight complete sentences. However equation numbers like \eqref{eq:energy} are tricky }{Highlight}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\protect` the fragile `\eqref`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}
\usepackage[author={Max Schlepzig}]{pdfcomment}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Following is energy equation
\begin{align}
\label{eq:energy}
    E=mc^2
\end{align}
\pdfmarkupcomment[markup=Highlight,color=yellow]{Of course, you can highlight complete sentences. However equation numbers like \protect\eqref{eq:energy} are tricky }{Highlight}
\end{document}
```

[image]